# send info to ldap server via command line

Tags: command-line-interface, ldap

I am working on an app that is going to require using the clients LDAP server. They have given  us the info and creditials. Is there any way I can, via the command line in LINUX, send a user/pass to their server and get a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLDAP's client tools take the DN to bind as via `-D`, and `-W` or `-w` is used for the password.